# PHP file inclusion in directory with an absolute link

Tags: php, file, directory, hyperlink

if I have 2 scripts:

```
includes/ajax_dir/script_1.php
```

and

```
includes/script_2.php
```

From `script_1.php` I know I can include `srcipt_2.php` like so:

```
include("../script_2.php");
```

however how could i do this include using an absolute link?...

Comment: You can use absolute filesystem path, i.e. /var/www/htdocs/your.php, but you can't use absolute URLs like http://your.domain/yourscript.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dirname(__FILE__)."/../"` will work great I think.

The reason I use `dirname(__FILE__)."/somepath/` everywhere is:

Imagine you have this folder structure

- /

  - index.php
  - /includes

    - /includes/include_libs.php
    - /includes/db.php
- /ajax

  - dostuff.php

```
//index.php
<?php
include("includes/include_libs.php");


// /includes/include_libs.php
<?php
include("includes/db.php"); //here is the problematical part

// /ajax/dostuff.php
<?php
include("../includes/include_libs.php"); /** 
    this will cause that include_libs tries to include /ajax/includes/db.php instead of /includes/db.php, to fix this trouble, change the problematical line in includes_libs.php to 

    include(dirname(__FILE__)."/db.php");

which will ensure that real db.php will be called */
```

Comment: nice... is this preferable to using the relative link above?... if so why?.. kind regards J.

Comment: @jon: because this ensures that you'll always include correct file, no matter what your cwd is.

Comment: Thanks Martin... however Im not sure i understand because I cant see when there would be a case that the relative link would pull the wrong file... however I will just take it as that it is always best to use absolute paths... thanks for you help in answering the question... regards J

Comment: @jon: I have changed my answer a lot, and I hope you'll get it now

Comment: Thanks Martin...  that makes sense to me... much appreciated... kind regards J

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
include(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)."../script_2.php"));
```

Comment: Thanks lkke, that works however it also gives an error:  [function.dir]: failed to open dir: Not a directory in ... Also what would be the advantage of doing it this way, as I would still need to know relative path... surely this is slower than just doing include("../script_2.php");    thanks for you help.